# Control the exit code of the locust process

Tags: locust

Receiving an error message (TypeError: _() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environment') with the following example code from the Locust Documentation on the following page:  https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/running-locust-without-web-ui.html

'''

```
import logging
from locust import events

@events.quitting.add_listener
def _(environment, **kw):
    if environment.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.01:
        logging.error("Test failed due to failure ratio > 1%")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.avg_response_time > 200:
        logging.error("Test failed due to average response time ratio > 200 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.get_response_time_percentile(0.95) > 800:
        logging.error("Test failed due to 95th percentile response time > 800 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    else:
        environment.process_exit_code = 0
```

'''

Comment: Huh. Strange. Can you share the full callstack? Just to check: you are on the latest version of locust, right? (1.0.3)

Comment: I tried exactly that code and it works for me...

Comment: Hi there, can anyone help me? I've copied this code into a file named 'conditions.py' then imported the code into my locustfile with 'from common.conditions import _' but the exit conditions are not working at all. Any suggestions on how make these exit conditions to be applied when reaching an exit condition? Also, I've tried to copy this exact code into my locustfile.py but these conditions are not working but they're reached.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve this issue by using the test stop event rather than the quitting event:

```
@events.test_stop.add_listener
def results(environment, **kw):
    if environment.stats.total.fail_ratio > 0.01:
        logging.error("Test failed due to failure ratio > 1%")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.avg_response_time > 200:
        logging.error("Test failed due to average response time ratio > 200 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    elif environment.stats.total.get_response_time_percentile(0.95) > 800:
        logging.error("Test failed due to 95th percentil response time > 800 ms")
        environment.process_exit_code = 1
    else:
        environment.process_exit_code = 0
```